# Wrong chars using PDO ODBC connection to DB2 on Windows

Tags: windows, pdo, db2, odbc, php-7

I’m setting up a new server, and I'm updating some old script (PHP 5+) to PHP 7.

I'm connecting to a DB2 database via PDO ODBC and reading a CHAR field with CCSID 870 and saving it on a MySQL mediumtext field in a table with `CHARSET=utf8`. But i got wrong characters on MySQL database and event in PHP console.

I tried to switch to `odbc_connect()` like the old script but the results was the same.

Even saving the field in a txt file the results is the same.

`utf8_encode` & `utf8_decode` doesn't help.

Here an example of code:

```php
$as = new PDO("odbc:MYODBC",$user, $psw);
$as->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$res = $as->query("SELECT FIELD FROM MYTABLE");
$rows = $res->fetchAll();

$mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=srvip;dbname=mydbname;charset=utf8",$user, $psw);
$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$ins = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO my_MySQL_TABLE (FIELD) VALUES (?)");
$ins->execute(array(trim($rows[0]["FIELD"])));
```

I expect the results on MySQL to be `Wąż`, but the actual output is `W??` or `WÈØ`.

## Edit on 2019-06-06

```
| Source           | String | HEX        |
|------------------|--------|------------|
| DB2              | Wąż    | E6A0B2     |
| MySQL            | W??    | 573F3F     |
| MySQL C/P Insert | Wąż    | 57C485C5BC |
```

The last version is a simple copy-paste to MySQL using a GUI

## Edit on 2019-06-07

```
C:\Users\ME\>echo %DB2CODEPAGE%
1208

C:\Users\ME\>acs.exe /PLUGIN=cldownload /system=MYSYS /sql="SELECT FIELD as char,HEX(FIELD) as hex FROM TABLE" /display=1
CHAR   HEX                                                                                                                                                    
W??    E6A0B2
```

If I use `/clientfile=test.txt` instead of `/display=1` Notepad++ show me the file as UTF-8

Comment: On the Windows hostname where the Db2-client is running, set system environment variable DB2CODEPAGE=1208, reboot and retry.

Comment: I just tried but the result is the same

Comment: Do a test. SELECT colname, hex(colname) from the Db2 table, then do the same from the mysql table. Edit your question to show the host character, its hex code (presumably in EBCDIC , but you need to check this), and then its converted utf-8 code.

Comment: Ignore PHP temporarily, can you SELECT those three characters again, for example at the shell command-line of your workstation and save to a file then show the hex codes in that file. This is to see if the db2-client is doing the bad translation. EBCDIC ccsid 870 0xE6 should become 0x57 in utf-8, 0xA0 should become 0xC485, and 0xB2 should become 0xC5BC, and VERIFY that at the command line the environment variable DB2CODEPAGE=1208

Comment: If notepad++ shows the *correct* characters then it means that the Db2-client is correctly doing the codepage conversion.  If you want to view the utf-8 characters in cmd.exe then use both a lucida-console font in that cmd.exe window  and run CHCP with a codepage-number *before* running the query (e.g. try chcp 1252, or chcp 65001). Back to your question, seems your PHP or your code is the issue, is your code converting again  after Db2-client has already done the correct job?  Check each option you are using.

Comment: There isn't any iconv,utf8_[encode/decode] or function that convert the string again. `chcp` and font didn't change console output results.